# Backup IMAP Email Account to a Hosted Google Account

Tags: linux, email, migration

I have a vanilla IMAP account for work, and they also provisioned me a hosted Google email account.

I have tried good ol' drag-and-drop migration with Thunderbird on more than a few occasions, and it was a miserable failure.  I am now interested in using a proper syncing tool, and scripting it effectively so I no longer have to work about running up against a quota.

Has anyone used [`imapsync`](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-migrate-mailboxes-between-imap-servers-with-imapsync) with good results?  If not, do they recommend any other migration tools?  I would love if someone could **confirm the ability of imapsync to map to different folder paths (think Inbox -> Inbox.JanuaryToDecember2010)** or **any tool that can migrate to a path different than the original email folder location in the new account**.  It would make organizing really easy.

Comment: Related [Transferring lots of messages between IMAP accounts](http://superuser.com/questions/191719/transferring-lots-of-messages-between-imap-accounts)

Comment: Per your answers to [the post you linked](http://superuser.com/questions/191719/transferring-lots-of-messages-between-imap-accounts): 1) Not really what I am looking for 2) I am sure something opensource, imapsync or otherwise, must be better and 3) I email quota will probably run out soon enough that I do not have time to code a solution.  I would love (3), but I need some assurance it gets copied because this is work email and I am a coding amateur, to be honest.

Comment: No problems. Was just a suggestion. @alharaka

Answer (score 0):

You mention that there is a quota. Can you check to see if your work also offers POP? Sometimes that is the case even if it's not publicly stated. If so, you can use Gmail's [Mail Fetcher](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=21289) to check the account and grab new mail over POP. You can even set up SMTP at Gmail for outgoing mail from your work account through Gmail.

Comment: Sorry, but I know for a fact POP will not work on either end.  Our email engineers are an annoying bunch.  :-)

Comment: @alharaka I see. Well, it was worth a shot. Best of luck!