# Moving email to new server (imap)

Tags: email, imap, cpanel, plesk

I would like to know what the best solution is to move imap emails from one server, to another.
Both my sevrers do not support any migration tools.
I was told to download it to my local mchine using imap.
Then using th eother server i lost all emails when it was up.
Could anyone give me a good option to push download the email files an dpush them to the new server?

Answer (score 1):

Just use thunderbird, and copy each folder from one server to the other, I think.

Comment: I've tried that, didnt work. I lsot everything when i loaded the new server information. Any other options?

Comment: I think what Stefan was saying was to create a "new" account in Thunderbird for the new IMAP server, and once you're up, move the messages from the old account to the new account that is connected to the new IMAP server. Your messages will be put in the folder in your new account in Thunderbird and they will be synced with the new IMAP server.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know what the best solution is to move imap emails from one server, to another.

Use IMAP and a sync or migration tool. If you choose to use IMAP, I believe the question has already been answered at Super User. See [Transferring lots of messages between IMAP accounts](https://superuser.com/questions/191719/transferring-lots-of-messages-between-imap-accounts).

Anther option is trying to migrate one [possibly proprietary] database to another. There's no need for that since the IMAP protocol abstracts away the application details like a database schema.